# Creating custom alias in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, alias

I'm following along with tutorial videos to learn Java, and I'm using IntelliJ IDEA for my IDE.

If I type `sout` and then tab, it auto-expands to `System.out.println();` , but I have the bad habit of typing `south` rather than `sout`.  Is it possible to add `south` as a custom alias to the IDE for auto-expanding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aliases are not supported, but plain old copy/paste will do the job:

[image: copy]

Select the group and paste into it from the group context menu:

[image: Paste]

Now change the abbreviation to `south` and define the context.

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thank you!

Comment: no more window.console.log in javascript just: cmd+j + log :D